# Inject custom data attribute to REACT `props.children`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component that only render `props.children`, but I'd like to inject some custom data attribute to the DOM element that it renders.

Let's look at an example:

```
const Decorator = props => {
    return props.children;
}

const Child = props => {
    return <div>I'm a child</div>
}

- - -

// Suppose we have this:
<Decorator><Child /></Decorator>

// Then, the DOM output will be:
<div>I'm a child</div>
```

Now, from the example above what I'd like to achieve is that any DOM element rendered via `Decorator` has a custom data attribute, so:

```
// Suppose we have this:
<Decorator><Child /></Decorator>

// Then, the DOM output will be:
<div data-decorator-attr="foo">I'm a child</div>
```

I've searched here and there, but I haven't found a way to do this. Here's the list of possibilities that I have thought about and the reasons why they cannot be used:

- Inside `<Decorator>` I could use `React.cloneElement` and inject a `ref` to `props.children`, but the `ref` would reference the component itself, and NOT the rendered DOM. I would need to export `Child` element using `React.forwardRef` but this is not viable (that's because `<Decorator>` could wrap anything, and I cannot edit all other component to be `React.forwardRef`;
- Being a functional component, I can't even use `React.findDOMNode` using the reference to the component itself;
- Inside `<Decorator>`, I cuold wrap `props.children` with a `<Fragment>`, but `<Fragment>` doesn't support `ref`;

So.. I have no idea how I could achieve this. The only way I found out is to renders a wrapper DOM element in the `<Decorator>`, like this:

```
const Decorator = props => {
    return <div style={{display: 'contents'}}>{props.children}</div>;
}
```

But what I wanted was to NOT have any wrapper DOM element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm super late on this, but I also bumped into the same problem recently.

This is what I came up with:

### Decorator Component

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

interface DecoratorProps {
  attr: string;
  children: React.ReactElement;
}

const Decorator: React.FC<DecoratorProps> = props => {
  const [parentElement, setParentElement] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);
  const Wrapper = parentElement ? React.Fragment : 'div';
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const targetIndex = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current?.parentElement) {
      targetIndex.current = Array.from(ref.current.parentElement.children).indexOf(ref.current);
      setParentElement(ref.current.parentElement);
      return;
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    parentElement?.children[targetIndex.current].setAttribute('data-decorator-attr', props.attr);
  }, [parentElement, targetIndex, props.attr]);

  return <Wrapper ref={parentElement ? undefined : ref}>{props.children}</Wrapper>;
};

export default Decorator;
```

### Usage

```
<Decorator attr="foo">
  <Button>...</Button>
</Decorator>
```

### Output

```
<button data-decorator-attr="foo">...</button>
```

---

If the component expects multiple children, you can modify the component to accept multiple children (you might have to filter Nodes though).

```
    if (parentElement && parentElement.firstChild instanceof HTMLElement) {
      parentElement.children.forEach(child => {
        child.dataset.decorator.attr = props.attr;
      });
    }
```

Comment: So.. Basically you first wrap the `<Child>` with a `<div>`, takes the inner element via DOM, and then remove the wrapper `<div>` and render via Fragment.. Right?

Comment: I wrap the `<Child>` with a `<div>` to locate the parent element. 
After I found the parent, I remove the wrapper `<div>`, then locate target element from parent to apply `data-attr` attribute.

This is to avoid missing `ref` or `data-attr` attribute when I remove the wrapper by replacing `<div>` with `<React.Fragment>` or other DOM transform from state updates.

Comment: I updated the code to prevent `data-decorator-attr` possibly being set to wrong element, when there are multiple siblings.

Comment: Quite impressing and at the same time disappointing (in me) that I didn't think of this! I'll mark as correct answer since I don't find any major withdraw (except the need of two renders)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps:

```js
const Decorator = props => {
  const elements = React.Children.toArray(props.children).map(
    (element) => React.cloneElement(element, { 'data-decorator-attr': 'foo' })
  );
  
  return <React.Fragment>{elements}</React.Fragment>;
};

const Child = props => <div {...props}>I'm a child</div>;

const App = () => <Decorator><Child /><div>Just a div</div></Decorator>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I used https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/passing-data-props-children/ as a reference.

Comment: This approach would work if all the `<Child>` component would pass the `{...props}` to it first rendered DOM element, like in your example. But, as I said, `<Child>` might be anything, even a simple `<div>`, so I cannot rely on that passing props. Thanks for trying, though :)

Comment: This example would also work with a plain div. See edit. If passing props to React components is still an issue I would be thinking about maybe mapping over element.children recursively until plain html components are found and altering those ... but that sounds messy so I'm not sure that would be a good way of going about things. Unless I've not understood what you're trying to achive.

Comment: What I meant is that, you write this `Child = props => <div {...props}>I'm a child</div>;`, but since `Child` component could be actually any component in my repository, I cannot rely on the fact that it pass `{...props}` to its child.
What I mean is that I must support case where I have `Child = props => <div>I'm a child</div>;`